# How to read csv with kdb without knowing csv datatype

Tags: string, csv, types, kdb

I have a csv file a.csv with 100 columns of data. The data type of each column is single, but I don’t know the specific type of each column, so I can’t give the correct data type when reading. Can kdb be like Python Does read_csv() seem to be able to parse and get a basically correct data type table without passing in the data type?

I try to read like this：

```
fntp:100#"*"
data:(fntp;enlist ",")0:`:a.csv
```

In this way, the data can be read, but the data of all columns are of string type, which does not meet my expectations. How can kdb read the table of the correct data type like Pandas' read_csv.

Comment: There's a CSV Lint plug-in for Notepad++ https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint which can infer the column datatypes based on the data. And it can generate a CREATE TABLE script from the menu `CSV Lint > Convert data > SQL` See also here https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/yqgnxs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method to guess the types of columns like in Python.

How about trying this [csvguess](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/csvguess.q) script?

Comment: [csvutil](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/csvutil.q) could help me.